# Select single row for each group from BigQuery group_by

Tags: group-by, google-bigquery

How to select any single full row from a group_by group in bigquery.

Given a table `foo` with columns `[a, b, c, d, e, f]` I would like to select any full row for each value of `a`. What would be a reasonable syntax here?

Existing [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70780661/bigquery-sql-select-first-row-of-each-group) addresses selecting only a single column, not a whole row.
[PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group) allows to do it using `DISTINCT ON (a)` but this is not available in BQ.

Comment: from the linked question although it selects one column, with partition by you should be able to select *, row_number() over (partition by a order by a) in bigquery. If you can give sample input and output you expect will be make it easy to provide appropriate response.

Comment: What would be the difference between simply filtering `a` from `UNNEST`ed elements from grouped columns and what you want? `WITH dataset AS (select ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'] as group_column) SELECT * FROM dataset as d WHERE ('a' in UNNEST(d.group_column))`

Comment: You might want to check QUALIFY with [`ROW_NUMBER`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70148035/what-is-the-advantage-of-using-bigquery-s-qualify-operator/70149163#70149163).

Answer (score 0):

This is not great (for example, any non-deterministic filtering [like `LIMIT 1000`] on the first table would brake the script because double querying the table, but it does the job:

```
WITH
numbered as (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY a) AS row_num 
   FROM `foo` ORDER BY a 
),

firsts as (
   select ANY_VALUE(row_num) as row_num from numbered
   group by job_id
),

single_record_per_group as (
   select a.* 
   from numbered as a
   inner join firsts as b
   on a.row_num = b.row_num 
)

SELECT * FROM single_record_per_group
```

If another column contains unique values only, it is better to use it instead of `row_num`

Answer (score 0):

This will give you a row number for each value of A

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A) AS RN
FROM some_table_you_did_not_name
```

You could also use an ORDER BY clause if you have a requirement to pick the first one

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B) AS RN
FROM some_table_you_did_not_name
```

Now just take the first one.

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f 
FROM (
  SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY A ORDER BY B) AS RN
  FROM some_table_you_did_not_name
) X
WHERE RN = 1
```